# inconsistent deduction for auto

Tags: c++, templates, auto

Can someone explain to me why the following code gives an error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename aa, typename bb>
auto minimum(aa a, bb b)
{
        if (a < b) return a;
        else return b;
}

int main()
{
    cout << minimum(7, 5.1);
}
```

> inconsistent deduction for 'auto': 'int' and then 'double'

Why does this code work without error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename aa, typename bb>
auto minimum(aa a, bb b)
{
     return a < b ? a : b;    
}

int main()
{
    cout << minimum(7, 5.1);
}
```

Comment: For deduction with more than one return statement to work, types in all return statements must match. There's no automatic promotion to the common type or anything like that. OTOH in a ternary operator there is an automatic conversion of tge two branches to the common type before any deductiin has a chance to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody smarter than me can cite the relevant part of the standard, but the short version is that the ternary operator works differently than `if`/`else`.  With the first example (`if`/`else`), you have two *distinct* `return`s, and you're *potentially* `return`ing different types (you do this in your example).  The function has to `return` a single type, so it doesn't know which is correct (i.e., whether to promote `int` to `double` or degrade `double` to `int`).

In your second example, the ternary operator can figure out the appropriate type based on the arguments (specially the latter two).  In your example, it will always treat the result as `double`, so your function knows that's what it needs to `return`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you have 2 separate `return` statements returning different data types, as `a` is an `int` and `b` is a `double`, so the `auto` doesn't know which data type to deduce.

In the second case, the result of the `?:` operator is 1 specific data type, and there is only 1 `return` statement, so there is no confusion for `auto` to know which data type to deduce.